# How to loop back to the beginning of the code on Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

After I type 5 usernames, it stops itself. How can I prevent that.

```
username = ['admin','bill','kevin','mike','nick']

for user in username:
 name = input("Please enter a username: ")
 if name == 'admin':
    print("Hello "+ name.title() + " ,would you like to see a status report?")
 else:
  if name in username:
   print("Hello " + name.title() + " thank you for logging in!")
  else:
      if name not in username:
          print("Who are you " + name.title() + " ? ")
```

Comment: Your first string iterates over the list of name. You should use an infinite loop instead.

Comment: As mentioned above, you are using a for loop, which iterates over whatever data you intend to iterate over, but only once. A while loop could be used until some future condition is met. It stops after 5 because you only have 5 elements in your username list, and again the for loop iterates over everything in that list only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
username = ['admin','bill','Kevin','mike','nick']
while True :

    name =input("Please enter a username: ")
    if name=='admin' :
        print("Hello "+ name + " ,would you like to see a status report?")
        break
    elif name in username :
        print("Hello " + name.title() + " thank you for logging in!")
        break
    else:
        print("Who are you " + name.title() + " ? ")
```

Comment: if you want the code to keep asking you to input a username regardless of the  printed statement just remove the two breaks .

Answer (score 0):

You can use infinity loop. This is an example.
"while True" works forever.

```
username = ['admin','bill','kevin','mike','nick']  
while True:
    name = input("What's your nickname?")
    if(name in username):
        print("Hello " + name + "! Thank you for logging in!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking something like this:

```
username = ['admin','bill','Kevin','mike','nick']
while True:
    while True :
    name = input("Please enter a username: ")
    if name=='admin' :
        print("Hello "+ name + " ,would you like to see a status report?")
        answer = input()
        if answer == 'yes':
            print('report')
        break;

    if name in username :
        print("Hello " + name.title() + " thank you for logging in!")
        break;
    else:
        print("Who are you " + name.title() + " ? ")
        break;
```

Use a while True loop inside another so whenever the second loop breaks,  will loop back to the first one.

Hope this help.